# The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period while creating a Logic App action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a Logic App in Azure. I am getting the error

> The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period.

when I try to add an action step in the designer. The action step when it is opening tries to search connectors and actions but then displays this message.
I use two Azure subscriptions, for one subscription the Logic App actions can be created, for the other one it fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, when the Built-in tab is clicked then the HTTP action can be selected.